# Enhancing Join and Group Performance with Spark DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

**INPUT:**

I have the two datasets:

1. `samples_1` dataset, which has the following columns:`timestamp, id, x, y`, and 500M records.
2. `samples_2` dataset, which has the same columns as `sample_1`, and 50M records.

**NOTES:**

- In a single dataset, the `timestamp` and `id` form the unique key of
  each record, i.e., `timestamp` and `id` alone can be duplicated.
- Across datasets, `id` from one dataset cannot be replicated on the other one. Still, `timestamp` can be duplicated across the two datasets.
- My cluster contains a driver node and five slave nodes each has 16 cores and 64 GB of RAM.
- I'm assigning 15 executors for my job, each has 5 cores and 19GB of RAM.

**QUESTION:**

What I'm trying to do is: for each `(timestamp_1, id_1)` tuple in `sample_1`, I need to find all `(timestamp_2, id_2, x_2, y_2)`s from `sample_2` where `timestamp_1` equals `timestamp_2`.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

```
samples_2
  .withColumn("combined", struct("id", "x", "y"))
  .groupBy("timestamp")
  .agg(collect_list("combined").as("combined_list"))
  .join(samples_2, Seq("timestamp"), "rightouter")
  .map {
    case Row(timestamp: String, samples: mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema], id_1: String, x_1: Float, y_1: Float) =>
      val overlappingSamples = samples.map {case Row(id_2: String, x_2: Float, y_2: Float) => (id_2, x_2, y_2)}

      if(overlappingSamples.nonEmpty) {
        val stringifiedSamples = overlappingSamples.map(x => s"${x._1}:${x._2}:${x._3}")
        (timestamp, id_1, stringifiedSamples.mkString("&"))
      } else {
        (timestamp, id_1,"", "")
      }

    case Row(timestamp: String, _, id_1: String, x_1: Float, y_1: Float) => // no overlapping samples
      (timestamp, id_1, "", "")

  }
  .write
  .csv(outputPath)
```

I have tried this code (using smaller datasets), and it gave the results I'm looking for. The issue here is that it becomes seriously slow when I ran it against the larger datasets. I read that I need to configure the number of partitions through `--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=5000`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in the above query is that there are too many shuffle operations tied to each other. I didn't check the actual logic of the join but there is a common issue in spark that needs to be handled.

In my opinion, when the execution DAG becomes long in SPARK it becomes little fragile. The reason is the any failure in the first stage requires recomputation the whole DAG.

The strategy I take is to breake the DAG or lineage in multiple smaller DAGs by persisting the result of each join.

```
val result = datasetA.join(datasetB).persist()
result.count // forces the materialization
// use the result variable in other join
```

> Here the count is mandatory as like other operations spark persist is lazy and require an explicit action (count) to force the join and materialization of the result.

You could try the same for your job and check the performance.

Comment: I called the count method after joining and started getting many failures. Regarding the performance nothing's changed.

Comment: I would suggest after the group by save the data in disk, read and then do the join. There is one more issue of data skew. Do you know if your data have skew or not?